# Converting SQL Select * statement into a delete statement

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL statement that pulls records from my database that matches a condition.

```
SELECT * FROM `t_questions` LEFT JOIN `t_syllabus` ON `t_syllabus`.`syllabus_id` =    `t_questions`.`question_syl_reference_id` WHERE `t_syllabus`.`syllabus_training_block` = 'CPL';
```

This works correctly and returns everything I want.

I now need to write a state to delete questions using the same condition.

So far I have tried this but I get an error.

```
DELETE FROM t_questions WHERE question_id IN(SELECT * FROM `t_questions` LEFT JOIN `t_syllabus` ON `t_syllabus`.`syllabus_id` = `t_questions`.`question_syl_reference_id` WHERE `t_syllabus`.`syllabus_training_block` = 'CPL')
```

I don't have the error message at hand but will update later.

Any ideas why this doesnt work?

Thanks.

Comment: "question_id IN(SELECT * FROM " You are selecting multiple values and comparing it against a single column (question_id)

Do a select on the question_id and it should work
(SELECT question_id FROM..)

Comment: @User Welcome to SO, be sure to check an answer that you like and upvote those that helped you!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM t_questions 
WHERE question_id IN
              (SELECT question_id  
               FROM `t_questions`.`t_questions` LEFT JOIN `t_syllabus` ON `t_syllabus`.`syllabus_id` = `t_questions`.`question_syl_reference_id`
               WHERE `t_syllabus`.`syllabus_training_block` = 'CPL')
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, you are selecting multiple values in your sub select.

You might be interested in doing an exists here. Exists queries are frequently much better optimized and therefore faster than in.

It would look like this:

```
DELETE FROM t_questions as t_outer
WHERE exists
              (SELECT 1
               FROM `t_questions`.`t_questions` as t_inner 
               LEFT JOIN `t_syllabus` ON `t_syllabus`.`syllabus_id` = `t_questions`.`question_syl_reference_id`
               WHERE `t_syllabus`.`syllabus_training_block` = 'CPL'
               AND t_inner.question_id = t_outer.question_id)
```